# Swift_TransportException Connection to ssl://mail.mydomain_name.com:465

Tags: laravel

I am working with laravell 8.77.1 . When I am trying to send from my application, gettig this error

Swift_TransportException Connection to ssl://mail.mydomain_name.com:465

Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport::getFullResponse
vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:475.

I am new to Laraval.

Any help would be apperciated.

Answer (score -1):

You should enter a valid mail server and all other properties in your .env file.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```